# Convert dataframe index with format YYYYMM and type 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index' to datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a dataframe `df`. I tried to convert it to DateTime index but didn't get an exact solution yet.

```
         India    China
date    
2018M06     2        1
2018M05     1        2
2018M04     3        1
   .       .        .
   .       .        .
   .       .        .
```

Here date in an index of dataframe type 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index' .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pd.to_datetime` on the index:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y%m')

>>> df
            India  China
date                    
2018-06-01      2      1
2018-05-01      1      2
2018-04-01      3      1
```

**[EDIT: for your edited input datatframe]**:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%YM%m')

>>> df
            India  China
date                    
2018-06-01      2      1
2018-05-01      1      2
2018-04-01      3      1
```

Comment: thanks @sacul there was mistake in question I updated my index field its 2018M06.